# In QML, where is the data of vertex coordinates stored in Mesh?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm a Qt newbie. I managed to load ".obj" file and show the 3D model using Mesh in my "main.qml". In fact, all I did was just setting the source of the file. With the help of an "ObjectPicker", I can know the indices of the triangle vertices. However, I don't know how to reach the coordinates of those vertices.

The Mesh loads the data itself. Since I didn't write the geometry, attributes and buffers for it, where and how can I get the vertex coordinates?

Part of the code is shown below. I set the picking method as TrianglePicking. Thanks a lot!

```
    Entity{
        id: part0Entity;
        objectName: "part0Entity";
        enabled: true;
        Connections{
            target: visEnt0;
            onClicked:{
                part0Entity.enabled = !part0Entity.enabled;
            }
        }
        Mesh{
            id: part0Mesh;
            source: "file:/home/zhaoyiji/Desktop/SF6-C1400/part0.obj"
        }

        Transform{
            id: part0Transform;
            matrix: Qt.matrix4x4();
        }
        DiffuseSpecularMaterial{
            id: part0Diffuse;
            ambient: "#80DC143C";
        }
        ObjectPicker{
            id: part0Picker;
            dragEnabled: true;
            onClicked: {
                if (pick.button == PickEvent.MiddleButton){
                    console.log(pick.worldIntersection)
                }
            }
        }

        components: [part0Mesh, part0Transform, part0Diffuse, part0Picker]
    }
```

Comment: why do you need the vertexes?

Comment: Because I want to do some trajectory planning. For example, move one point through each line created by the vertices. Do you know how? Thanks! @SajadBlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the raw data can be accessed as follows:

**In main.cpp:**

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
auto part0Mesh = view.rootObject()->findChild<Qt3DRender::QMesh *>("part0Mesh");
qDebug()<<part0Mesh->geometryFactory()->operator()()->attributes().value(0)->buffer()->data();
```

**In qml:**

```
Mesh{
    id: part0Mesh;
    objectName: "part0Mesh";
    source: "file:/YourFilePath/YourFileName.obj"
}
```

This is for QMesh's auto loading. There will be a functor to load the data from the source we set. The `geometryFactory()` returns a QSharedPointer pointing to it, and then `operator()()` returns the geometry. If we build the buffers, the attributes and the geometry on our own, then we can access the data simply by:

```
part0Mesh->geometry()->attributes().value(0)->buffer()->data();
```

Figured it out by reading the source code of **qmesh.cpp**. Hard for a newbie ;)